# Django QuerySet - Joining tables on id in array

Tags: django, postgresql, django-queryset

I've been having some difficulty figuring out how to implement the following PostgreSQL query using Django query set notation:

```
SELECT *
FROM t1 
JOIN t2 ON t1.a = ANY(ARRAY[t2.d]);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Edit:

Tables:

```
  t1        t2                 t_join
  ---      ---                 ------   
  a b      c d                 a b c d 
1 w x    1 p {s, t, w}       1 w x p {s, t, w}
2 y z    2 q {r, y, w}       2 w x q {r, y, w} 
                             3 y z q {r, y, w}
```

Models:

```
class t1(models.Model):
    a = models.CharField(max_length=10, primary_key=True)
    b = models.IntegerField(null=True)

class t2(models.Model):
    c = models.CharField(max_length=10, primary_key=True)
    d = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=10))
```

Comment: Could you give an example of what this Join has to produce?

Comment: And show your models.

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is sort of what you want?  With the table 1 data repeated in each row for each instance of table 2 data, and nothing if there's no corresponding entry?  I don't think I understand the role of array_column properly.

```
 t1          t2         t_join
 --          --         ------   
  a b      c t1_id      a b c 
1 w x    1 p  1       1 w x p
2 y z    2 q  1       2 w x q
```

The call '[select_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#select-related)' will pick up every t2 row for each t1 row, if your ORM defines the ForeignKey relationship in the right direction.  Something like this would be worth a shot:

```
table1.objects.select_related('table2')
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! That's not quite what I meant - I've added tables to my question to clarify.

Comment: If you can get Daniel Roseman to help you should - like Fatboy Slim, 'that guy kicks ass'. Could you show your models? I'm a bit out of my depth.  If I had this problem, I would probably try to solve it by converting the arrayfield to its own table with t2.pk as a foreign key. I would then expect to be able to chain 'select_related' through the three tables.  Getting to a table out of that joined queryset could probably be done (slowly) with looping, but I'm pretty sure there is a much better way, but I don't know what it is.

Comment: Yeah fair enough - I think I may just need to rearrange my tables so that this join is unnecessary...